# htaccess redirect conditions

Tags: .htaccess

I figured out how to redirect someone, if they happen across one particular filename:

```
Redirect /index.php http://www.website.com/#myaccount
```

As you can see, I'm pretty much redirecting that visitor to the same page, which doesn't work. It's an endless look, regardless of the slight/minuscule change.

I want to force someone to see a part of the page, by adding the hash.  (it's a little weird, I know)

I'm guessing this may be a time to use regex in the htaccess file.
But I thought I'd ask if there's a simpler way to do this from the htaccess file.

Comment: Do you actually mean to redirect the user from the same page they are coming from to a particular portion of that page?  This will make it impossible to access the page without jumping down the page.

Comment: It's not a little weird so much as it is just plain dumb. Conditional presentation logic doesn't really belong in your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment of an URI (the part after the first `#`) is not sent to the server. That means you cannot use server side techniques to test if the fragment has a certain value of does exist at all; only client side techniques like JavaScript can do that.